# Code does not contain a static Main method suitable for entry point

Tags: c#

I have a problem with this code that I have been writing.. I constantly get an error message that says that "*Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point*". The code is supposed to run a tennis game. I know that i haven't inserted a Main string or a Console.ReadLine anywhere, because it seems that wherever I do this, I get an error.. Please understand that I am fairly new at C#.

So I am asking in here hoping that someone can show me how to make this program run a match, because it seems that all I need is a main method or Console.ReadLine somewhere?

Thank you in advance!

```
namespace testmatch
{
public interface ITennisGame
{
    void WonPoint(string playerName);
    string GetScore();
}
}
```

*/

```
namespace testmatch
{
public class TennisGame2 : ITennisGame
{
    private int p1point;
    private int p2point;

    private string p1res = "";
    private string p2res = "";
    private string player1Name;
    private string player2Name;

    public TennisGame2(string player1Name, string player2Name)
    {
        this.player1Name = player1Name;
        p1point = 0;
        this.player2Name = player2Name;
    }

    public string GetScore()
    {
        var score = "";
        if (p1point == p2point && p1point < 3)
        {
            if (p1point == 0)
                score = "Love";
            if (p1point == 1)
                score = "Fifteen";
            if (p1point == 2)
                score = "Thirty";
            score += "-All";
        }
        if (p1point == p2point && p1point > 2)
            score = "Deuce";

        if (p1point > 0 && p2point == 0)
        {
            if (p1point == 1)
                p1res = "Fifteen";
            if (p1point == 2)
                p1res = "Thirty";
            if (p1point == 3)
                p1res = "Forty";

            p2res = "Love";
            score = p1res + "-" + p2res;
        }
        if (p2point > 0 && p1point == 0)
        {
            if (p2point == 1)
                p2res = "Fifteen";
            if (p2point == 2)
                p2res = "Thirty";
            if (p2point == 3)
                p2res = "Forty";

            p1res = "Love";
            score = p1res + "-" + p2res;
        }

        if (p1point > p2point && p1point < 4)
        {
            if (p1point == 2)
                p1res = "Thirty";
            if (p1point == 3)
                p1res = "Forty";
            if (p2point == 1)
                p2res = "Fifteen";
            if (p2point == 2)
                p2res = "Thirty";
            score = p1res + "-" + p2res;
        }
        if (p2point > p1point && p2point < 4)
        {
            if (p2point == 2)
                p2res = "Thirty";
            if (p2point == 3)
                p2res = "Forty";
            if (p1point == 1)
                p1res = "Fifteen";
            if (p1point == 2)
                p1res = "Thirty";
            score = p1res + "-" + p2res;
        }

        if (p1point > p2point && p2point >= 3)
        {
            score = "Advantage player1";
        }

        if (p2point > p1point && p1point >= 3)
        {
            score = "Advantage player2";
        }

        if (p1point >= 4 && p2point >= 0 && (p1point - p2point) >= 2)
        {
            score = "Win for player1";
        }
        if (p2point >= 4 && p1point >= 0 && (p2point - p1point) >= 2)
        {
            score = "Win for player2";
        }
        return score;
    }

    public void SetP1Score(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            P1Score();
        }
    }

    public void SetP2Score(int number)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            P2Score();
        }
    }

    private void P1Score()
    {
        p1point++;
    }

    private void P2Score()
    {
        p2point++;
    }

    public void WonPoint(string player)
    {
        if (player == "player1")
            P1Score();
        else
            P2Score();

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you googled: "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" ?

Comment: Several times.. And I have tried to insert it a lot of places, but nothing seems to work..?

Comment: All C# programs must have a static method Main to start. The error is self explanatory! 

internal class Program { private static void Main() { // Call your code here } }

Comment: @sigwa: I doubt that because as result i get many stackoverflow questions with the same issue and good answers

Answer (score 9):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong:

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point

You are missing an entry point of your program:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You don't need entry point like this for DLL libraries as they are not meant to be executed, you don't need it for web apps that you host on IIS as IIS knows how to run it (Exception is self-hosted web apps) but they are required for console apps.